# BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 is very noise?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` as code below

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgr;
double learningRate = 0.05;
(bgr)(img_input, img_mask, learningRate);
```

But the result is not good, there are many noise foreground pixels here (figure below)
[image]

When I use BackgroundSubtractorMOG as code below

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG bgr(81, 3, 0.1);
double learningRate = 0.05;
(bgr)(img_input, img_mask, learningRate);
```

The result is better, but this method is slower (figure below) 
[image]

I want to use BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 because it is faster, but the result is very noise.

Someone can show me the correctly way to use BackgroundSubtractorMOG2?

Thank you!

T&T

Comment: you call that "very" noisy? If you want speed + quality, try ViBe. There exists a Demo application (where you can see whether the quality is ok for you). Method is very easy to implement, but patented.

Comment: @Micka: Thank you, I have try to use Vibe algorithm that implemented by BgsLibrary, Its quality is good, but the its speed is slower than BackgroundSubtractorMOG.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use morphological operation on the output?

```
vector<vector<Point >> contours;
Mat kernel=getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size(5,5));
Mat kernel2=getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size(10,10));
morphologyEx(img_mask,img_mask,CV_MOP_ERODE,kernel);
morphologyEx(img_mask,img_mask,CV_MOP_DILATE,kernel2);

findContours(img_mask,contours,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
drawContours(img_input,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(255,255,255),2);
output=img_input.clone();
```